# How to set a consistent location for drives mounted on boot?

Tags: hard-drive, startup, mount, diskutil

Each time I reboot my computer, when I run `diskutil list` the order of the mounted drives changes: /dev/disk0 becomes /dev/disk1 and vice versa. This creates problems for applications and scripts that depend on finding specific information in a consistent location. So far, the only (unreliable) solution is to reboot the computer hoping the paths correct themselves.

I have also seen this question but none of the answers seemed to be a reliable long-term fix: [Can I set a mount order via stab](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387528/can-i-set-a-mount-order-via-stab)

Is there a way to set how the drives mount on boot so they are always at the same mounting location/path?

Update:
I have found a similar question for Ubuntu here where the solution is to update the reference to drives to use their UUID. However, I have not found a similar UUID-based reference available in Mac: [VirtualBox raw drive using UUID instead of device name](https://superuser.com/questions/1322262/virtualbox-raw-drive-using-uuid-instead-of-device-name)

Comment: Why does the device numbering cause issues? Don't you access your drives via `/Volumes` afterwards?

Comment: Can you give an example of why a script or app would need to reference a disk by its device node (e.g., '/dev/disk1'), and not by more stable identifies like it UUID?

Comment: Yes, I run virtual machines via VirtualBox that point to the different drives by their drive number. The virtual machine images encode the device path and partition when the image is created. Additionally, I also run a set of scripts that prepare these drives for use by the virtual machine (unmounting & permissions) which also require the paths. Instructions: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220670/run-boot-camp-windows10-partition-inside-virtualbox and http://web.archive.org/web/20181103074214/http://danielphil.github.io/windows/virtualbox/osx/2015/08/25/virtualbox-boot-camp.html

Comment: I haven't seen anything like this, but if there is a way to create these images pointing to the various hard drive os installations without using their disk locations (including updates to setup scripts) this would also be an acceptable solution.

Comment: Can you post an example because that doesn't really make sense.  When you mount a drive you would address it by the mount point.  If VB is taking control of it using the drive identifier then you don't really need to mount it.  For instance, USB Filters would be an example here.

Comment: The issue here is that VB can't find the partitions specified in the .vmdk files when the device mount point changes. This means that the virtual machines fail to launch due to missing partitions unless I recreate the .vmdk image and associated scripts each time - a somewhat lengthy process.

Comment: @Allan, to specifically address your comment, you are right that VB needs the drive to be unmounted to be used. However, these are drives installed internally to my system so they are automatically mounted on boot, but each time at a different mount point. This causes my scripts that do the unmounting and the VB virtual machine disk files (.vmdk) to regularly break.

Comment: **macOS**, and at a lower level **BSD**, does **not** guarantee the device node numbering mount order (or something to that effect). **VMware Fusion** uses the **UUID** of an external disk when accessing **RAW** disks because of the lack of the aforementioned guarantee. It certainly sounds like **VirtualBox** hasn't figured that out and this is a **VirtualBox** problem, not a **macOS** problem.

Comment: @user3439894 I have found a similar problem statement but for Ubuntu here: https://superuser.com/questions/1322262/virtualbox-raw-drive-using-uuid-instead-of-device-name. In short, the solution there is to use the device UUID as a mount point in VB. However, I am not seeing that mac has '/dev/disk/by-uuid' or '/dev/disk/by-id' paths. Is there possibly another place that mac might put these mount points by UUID? I assume there likely is this kind of UUID-based mount point if this is how VMware Fusion does their connections but so far I haven't been able to find their location.

Comment: Krejko, It's been too many years since I've used use **RAW** disks in **VMware Fusion**, so my thoughts and memories are a bit foggy. I'll have to setup a **RAW** disk to a **VMDK** in **VMware Fusion** to examine it and see what it yields. I'll get back to you on it a bit later.

Comment: So I created a **VMDK** for a **RAW disk** while it was mounted a `/dev/disk3`, then ejected it, mounted another disk and then mounted the previous disk and it is now `/dev/disk4` and **VMware Fusion** had no problem accessing it and booting the **OS** on it. The **# Extent description** in the **.vmdk** _file_ is `RW 120127488 FLAT "/dev/disk3" 0 partitionUUID @disk:diskModel=Ultra,diskSize=61505273856,diskVendor=SanDisk` and as you can see it shows `/dev/disk3` even though it worked mounted as `/dev/disk4`. I'd imagine it's using other information in that to dynamically find the target.

Comment: I believe it's using the `partitionUUID` portion, being `@disk:diskModel=Ultra,diskSize=61505273856,diskVendor=SanDisk`.  to find the disk. There were a bunch of new files created at `/.fseventsd/` on the **Startup Disk** of that drive, but not sure how relevant it is.

Comment: What do you mean mounted “internally”?  Are they fixed disks like SATA drives or are they removable like a USB?  I’ve never seen the former  change the identifier on reboots. If you need a specific device use the UUID

Comment: To get the UUID of a drive, issue the command `diskutil info diskXsY | grep UUID` where X is the drive number and Y is the partition/slice.  Once you have that, you can issue your commands with the UUID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, it doesn't seem to be possible to set consistent disk locations. However, there are some workarounds that can be useful in certain workflows.

For my specific case:
While Allan's response had some helpful info that played a part in the final solution, it alone was not able to solve my issue.

The only way I was able to solve this issue was to upgrade my scripts that launch VirtualBox to also

1. Release the old virtual disk image then delete the .vmdk files
2. Create a new virtual disk image and set the permissions (using Allan's diskutil snippets)
3. Set the ownership for the new files
4. Update the new .vmdk files to match the old .vmdk UUID
5. Re-add the IDE controller and attach the .vmdk file as its medium
6. Launch the VM.

While this is far more involved than I had hoped, so far this has been a much more consistent solution to the issue where the drives change their order.

The full script can be found below:

```
  #release drives
  dev="/dev/"
  diskUUID=<the-disk-uuid>
  diskXs2=$dev$(diskutil list ${diskUUID} | awk 'FNR == 5 { print $7 }')
  diskXs4=$dev$(diskutil list ${diskUUID} | awk 'FNR == 7 { print $7 }')
  
  if grep -qs '/Volumes/Bootcamp ' /proc/mounts; then
      echo "Drive '/Volumes/Bootcamp' is now unmounted."
    sudo diskutil unmount /Volumes/Bootcamp
  else
      echo "Drive '/Volumes/Bootcamp' is not mounted."
  fi
  sudo chmod 777 ${diskXs2}
  sudo chmod 777 ${diskXs4
  # Detach old disk image
  vmUUID="<VM-UUID-HERE>"
  MAX_PORT=$(vboxmanage showvminfo ${vmUUID} |grep "Storage Controller Max Port Count (0)" | awk '{print $7}' );
  vboxmanage storagectl ${vmUUID} --name 'IDE' --portcount $MAX_PORT --remove
  
  # Make new disk image
  diskX=$(diskutil list ${diskUUID} | awk '/dev/ { print $1 } ')

  if ls win10raw* 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
    rm win10raw*  
  fi
  sudo /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -rawdisk ${diskX} -filename win10raw.vmdk -partitions 2,4 
  
  # Update the new .vmdk files to match the old .vmdk UUID
  oldVmdkUUID="<OLD_UUID>"
  sed -i '' "25s|.*|ddb.uuid.image=""${oldVmdkUUID}"" |" "win10raw.vmdk"

  
  if ls *.vmdk 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
      # echo "files do exist"
    sudo chown <MY-USER> *.vmdk
  fi

  # Attach new disk image
  /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage storagectl ${vmUUID} --name "IDE" --add ide
  /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage storageattach ${vmUUID} --storagectl IDE --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium "win10raw.vmdk"

  # Launch the VM
   nohup /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage startvm ${vmUUID} &
```

References:

- https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2926/get-a-list-of-all-your-virtualbox-virtual-machines-by-name-and-uuid-from-the-shell
- https://www.andreafortuna.org/2019/10/24/how-to-create-a-virtualbox-vm-from-command-line/
- https://organisemenet.wordpress.com/2017/01/05/bulk-delete-vbox-disk-medium/
- https://mezzantrop.wordpress.com/2016/10/18/quick-reference-for-adding-and-attaching-drives-in-virtualbox-cli/
- http://web.archive.org/web/20181103074214/http://danielphil.github.io/windows/virtualbox/osx/2015/08/25/virtualbox-boot-camp.html

Comment: This may have solved your issue, but it isn't an answer to the question you actually asked.

Comment: Thanks, Doug. I have updated my response to be more specific to the questions asked.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to set how the drives mount on boot so they are always at the same mounting location/path?

You don't need to specify the order in which they boot; you use the UUID.   To get the UUID of a drive in macOS use the command:

```
% diskutil info diskXsY | grep -i UUID
```

where X is the disk number (i.e. `/dev/disk5`) and Y is the slice or partition number (i.e. `disk5s1`)

For example, I inserted a random USB flash disk that identified as `/dev/disk7`.  Issuing the command as detailed above

```
% diskutil info disk7s1 | grep -i UUID
Volume UUID:               0E239BC6-F960-3107-89CF-1C97F78BB46B
Disk / Partition UUID:     DF8CB142-B426-4F62-841C-5D26904CF54C
```

The Disk UUID is the second entry.

So, to identify this disk anytime it's been attached to the Mac, you can use the UUID.  For example:

```
% diskutil list DF8CB142-B426-4F62-841C-5D26904CF54C
/dev/disk8 (external, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *16.0 GB    disk8
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk8s1
2:          Apple_CoreStorage MyTest                  15.7 GB    disk8s2
3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk8s3
```

If you notice, it now has an identifier of `disk8`.  I had inserted another USB flash forcing the drive identifier to change proving that this is a valid method.

If you must use the drive identifier, create a function that determines the identifier via the UUID. For example, the following command will get your the disk identifier of the attached drive with the UUID:

```
% diskutil list DF8CB142-B426-4F62-841C-5D26904CF54C | awk '/dev/ { print $1 } '

/dev/disk8
```

You could create a [Bash/Zsh function](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html) to return this info for you on demand.

Regarding non-removable media...

> Each time I reboot my computer, when I run diskutil list the order of the mounted drives changes: /dev/disk0 becomes /dev/disk1 and vice versa

I can't see this happening.  Non-removable media does not change.  Your boot device is specified in NVRAM meaning `/disk0` will be what you boot from and since it's defined in the *preboot environment* `disk0` and `disk1` will not swap places.  The only time this can happen is during Recovery (you're booting from a different volume) but then, when booting from Recovery, you're not loading anything there, especially your VB app.

Now, if you're referring to *removable* devices, yes, it is possible for the identifier to change (I did it in my example).  This is why you use the disk UUID to ensure you're always access the same drive regardless of when it gets attached.